# Unable to autoload constant Auction, expected /app/models/configuration/auction.rb to define it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have two classes `app/models/auction.rb` and `app/models/configuration/auction.rb`

```
#app/models/auction.rb
class Auction
end

#app/models/configuration/auction.rb
class Configuration::Auction
  attr_accessor :auction_preferences
end
```

I get the error

> Unable to autoload constant Auction, expected
>   /app/models/configuration/auction.rb to define it

when the below line is executed

```
(Configuration::Auction.new(user).enable_auction? ? Auction.get_details(user) : "NA")
```

Comment: Probably due to having *same name*? Try changing the name of any of the two models.

Answer (score 2):

Having two objects with the same core name can give the autoloader a headache on occasions, when it can't quite work out which namespace you intended.

You can try being more explicit with your second `Auction` object, and specify `::Auction` to indicate that you mean the non-namespaced class.

But I would also think about your naming scheme for configuration objects. Without knowing more about your object model it's hard to say for sure, but it may be that `AuctionConfiguration` would be a better model name for your config object.

Answer (score 0):

One likely root cause for the `LoadError error` is, that as of Rails 5.2.0, there are changes to autoload, that require submodules (namespaces) to (at the least) be defined (as a constant).

In the original post's example, the `module Configuration` should be defined in the `app/models/configuration.rb` file.

Refer to this [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64601195/2769838) for more details.