# "Unable to autoload constant" Bug in Rails 5.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, controller, autoload

I'm running a Rails 5.2.0 application. This `LoadError` always appears on the first request after a reboot or a recompile:

`Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::ApplesController, expected /fruits_and_vegetables/app/controllers/api/v1/apples_controller.rb to define it`

The pertinent files:

`routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get 'apples', to: 'apples#get'
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the file structure:

```
 - app
  - controllers
   - api
    - v1
     - apples_controller.rb
```

What's in `apples_controller.rb`:

```
class Api::V1::ApplesController < ApplicationController
   // stuff
end
```

A few posts on StackOverflow have suggested that this error is likely caused by a typo in my controller file, but that is not the case. Or, some folk have mentioned the case sensitivity of Rails. However, if I try to change `api` and `v1` to `Api` or `V1` in the `routes.rb` file or in the controller, Rails will throw up an error.

[I saw a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55397462/loaderror-unable-to-autoload-constant-in-rails) suggesting that one should run `rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'`, and if I don't see `/fruits_and_vegetables/app/controllers/api` in the output listing, then add `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("app/controllers/api")` to my `config/application.rb` file, but [it seems that is discouraged](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).

Any thoughts? I see at least a dozen similar posts on here, but no real concrete solution it seems?

Comment: have you tried defining your controller like this?:`module Api; module V1; class ApplesController < ApplicationController; end; end; end`. Add a new line where every `;` is and remove it from the code as well.

Comment: I am just beginning my upgrade to Rails 5.2.0 (from Rails 5.1.6.2) and have the same issue (when my application server starts). I tried the suggestion above (by fanta, i.e. to explicitly namespace the module/class by lines) that resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 10):

This same (LoadError) error occurred for my legacy Rails 5.1 application code, when I simply upgraded Rails to version 5.2.0. The fix (for me) was to add a missing source file that solely defines a submodule (to satisfy the autoloader). I will explain the fix in the context of the original post example.

In the original post, the `ApplesController` is part of the `V1` namespace. The problem is, that the `V1` submodule is not (explicitly) defined. The solution is to create a file, at the proper (autoload) path, that defines the `V1` module:

`app/controllers/api/v1.rb`

```
module Api
  module V1
  end
end
```

Apparently, as of Rails 5.2, the autoloader needs every module namespace to be explicitly defined. You can read the technical details about [Rails 5.2 constant autoloading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).

And a [related SO answer to the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61745803/2769838).

Comment: Jeff, should the v1.rb file be a child of the api directory or a child of the v1 directory? 

And so, a child of the api directory (and a sibling of the v1 directory)?


Or, a child of the v1 directory (and a sibling of the apples_controller.rb file)?


Thank you again for your help

Comment: As the answer shows above, the `v1.rb file` resides in the `api directory` (along with the `v1 directory`).